# How to internationalize a message in grails with a hashmap (key:value)

Tags: grails, internationalization

I need to translate a message key using a Hashmap using the Grails standard internationalization method.

I receive an Enum and a map with the binding, which are going to be replaced in the text. 
The Enum indicates, which key is going to be recovered. The bindings have the values to replace on the translation.

```
messageSource.getMessage("mail.layout.subject.${templateName}",ARGS,"",locale)
```

The problem is that I need to pass the map to the args like an array, not like a map, but I don't know the order of the args.

My question is, if there are any ways to create a tranlation key like:

```
mail.layout.subject.ENUM1=Blablabl {name} bablablabl {age}
```

Instead of

```
mail.layout.subject.ENUM1=Blablabl {0} bablablabl {1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is much cleaner. :)

```
import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine

def text = 'Dear "$firstname $lastname",So nice to meet you in ${city.name}.See you in ${month},${signed}'  
def binding = ["firstname":"Sam", "lastname":"Pullara", "city":["name":"San Francisco", "id":"28"], "month":"December", "signed":"Groovy-Dev"]  
def engine = new SimpleTemplateEngine()
template = engine.createTemplate(text).make(binding)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did it with brute force. May be is not the best answer but I coudln't find any one better.
Basically I get the translation with te message resources and then I work with it finding my custom  expresions.

```
def messageSource =  grailsApplication.getMainContext().getBean('messageSource')
def subject = messageSource.getMessage("mail.layout.subject.NOTIFICATION",null,"",locale)
```

An example of subject resource

```
mail.layout.subject.NOTIFICATION=The user {friend.name} is friend of {user}
```

An example bindings:

```
def bindings = [friend:[name:"Jhon",surname:"Smith"],user:"David"]
```

With this senteces I replace my expresions with the value of the bindings

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{[^}]+\\}")
def res = subject.replaceAll(pattern,{
     def expresion = it[1..it.size()-2] // removes brackets
     def fields = expresion.split("\\.");

     def res  = bindings
     fields.each{
     println(it)
         res = res."${it}"
     }
     return res

 })
```

After the proces the subject becomes like: "The user Jhon is friend of David"

The example use a HashMap of HashMaps, but it also works with object because grails/groovy handles the object like HashMaps and viceversa